# Como ejecutar una funcion cada milisegundo?

Tags: javascript

Ejecutar una funcion cada milisegundo

```js
window.onload = function() {
  main();

  function main() {
    int = setInterval('dibujar()', 100);
  }


  function dibujar() {
    console.log('dibujando');
  }
}
```

El script de arriba produce error y creo ques es por la funcion .onload, necesito el `window.onload = function() {}` porque sino lo uso me sale objetos null del html.
si no lo uso funciona bien(REPITO: necesito usar la funcion **`window.onload = function() {}`**):

```js
main();

      function main() {
        int = setInterval('dibujar()', 100);
      }


      function dibujar() {
        console.log('dibujando');
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se por que usas `int = setInterval` puedes usar `window.setInterval()` y hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```js
var intervalo;
window.onload = function (){
   initIntervalo();// funcion que inicia el intervalo
   
}
function initIntervalo(){
  intervalo = window.setInterval(myFunction,1);
    //Recorda que recibe como parametro los milisegundos. 
//Entonces si quieres que se ejecute cada 1 milisegundo debes idicarle 1 no 100 como pusiste.
}
 function myFunction (){
      console.log("Ejecutando");
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="window.clearInterval(intervalo)">Detener</button>
```

**Editado: Lo puedes hacer tranquilamente con window.onload. Debes recordar que es una función. Por lo tanto no puedes escribir funciones en su interior. También puedes almacenar el intervalo en una variable para poder tener acceso luego para detenerlo por ejemplo.**